# how to refer to extJS combobox using a string?

Tags: javascript, django, extjs

Is there any way to refer back via string to an instance of combobox?
I have a workaround in place, but not very happy with it, especially as i see the need to create more ComboBox's in the future.
i have tried unsuccessfully to use 'reference','id','itemId'.

The reason why i ask is b/c i am dumping meta information about my fields and the meta-info comes across as strings.
this works well until i need a javascript instance for my 'editor'.

i can not refer to a javascript instance when the info has quotes around it.
i am posting my code (just relevant portion) below with a comment near my issue/question/workaround.

```
var my_combo=Ext.create('Ext.form.field.ComboBox', {
    listClass: 'x-combo-list-small',
    store: ['string', 'int', 'number', 'boolean', 'date'],
    queryMode: 'local',
    displayField: 'data_type',
    valueField: 'data_type'
});

var center_grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    store: ourrecordstore,
    region: 'center',
    selModel: Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel'),
    selType: 'rowmodel',
    /*
    columns: {{grid_panel_columns|safe}},// <---this does not work b/c we need to use javascript variable, not something quoted. 
    if we could use a string to identify the data_type_combo object, that would be ideal.
    for now i am iterating across the dictionary and if the editor i want is data_type_combo, then i have code below to use the data_type_combo instance
    previously what you see on the next line was used (django template), but it failed when i needed to add drop downs via combobox.
    columns:[{{grid_panel_columns|safe}}]
    */
    columns: [{% for column in grid_panel_columns %}
                {% if column.editor == "data_type_combo" %}
                     {'filter': {'type': 'string'},'text': 'data_type', 'dataIndex': 'data_type','editor':my_combo},
                {% else %}
                    {{column|safe}},
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}],
    })
```

this is what the grid_panel_columns array looks like

```
'grid_panel_columns': [
    {'filter': {'type': 'string'}, 'text': 'name', 'dataIndex': 'name', 'editor': 'textfield'}, 
    {'filter': {'type': 'string'}, 'text': 'data_type', 'dataIndex': 'data_type', 'editor': 'data_type_combo'}, 
    {'filter': {'type': 'string'}, 'text': 'active', 'dataIndex': 'active', 'editor': 'textfield'}, 
    {'filter': {'type': 'string'}, 'text': 'id', 'dataIndex': 'id'}
],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if i understand right, but you want a specific combobox for your editor like `xtype: 'combo'`?

You can define a new xtype based on a combobox which can used as `editor: 'data_type_combo`.

Here is an example fiddle how you could achieve this: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/nup

Comment: what a fantastic example and explanation. thank you!

Comment: i thought it was working and am still quite thankful for the tips to use the alias.  
the problem i am having is that the store of alias 'widget.reference_combo' ends up being the same store of the other one.  
in other words, my drop down list is the same for the 2 columns.   
they should each have their own store.   
that is what makes them different from each other.

Comment: i define 2 combobox's ; each has a unique alias, store, valuefield, and displayField.

     Ext.define('Ext.form.field.DataTypeCombo', {
        extend: 'Ext.form.field.ComboBox',
        alias: ['widget.data_type_combo'],
        alternateClassName: ['Ext.form.DataTypeCombo'],
        store: ['string', 'int', 'number', 'boolean', 'date', 'other_table'],
        queryMode: 'local',
        displayField: 'data_type',
        valueField: 'data_type',
        initComponent: function() {
           this.callParent();
        }
    });

Comment: later in my Panel, i have them in quotes (thanks to alias working)
      columns: [
       {'filter': {'type': 'string'}, 'text': 'data_type', 'dataIndex': 'data_type', 'editor': 'data_type_combo'},
       {'filter': {'type': 'string'}, 'text': 'reference', 'dataIndex': 'reference', 'editor': 'reference_combo'}  
      ],

Comment: Either you have to define a second xtype for the reference or you have to create two object literals, configured as xtypes and add them as editor. Look at the posted fiddle in my answer for an example.